# gsi Google Sign in button not appearing in angular app

Tags: angular, google-signin

I was using 'angularx-social-login' for google sign-in in angular app. Now as this is deprecated hence I need to change this with the instructions mentioned in https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button link.
But after integrating this new approach, button is not appearing on my angular login page.

Here is the code that I had implemented -

index.html:

```
<body class="mat-typography" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
  <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"></script>
  <rtd-app-root></rtd-app-root>
  <app-redirect></app-redirect>
</body>
</html>
```

login.component.html:

```
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="<MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID>" data callback="handleCredentialResponse">
</div>
<div class="g_id_signin" data-type="standard"></div>
```

after viewing elements using "F12" - these two divs are appearing empty.

Requesting help to resolve this.

Comment: any luck getting this to work? I am stuck on google signin as well.